# What are the differences between 'Selenium-server-standalone.jar' and 'Selenium Client & WebDriver'?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid, selenium-rc

What are the Implementations differences between 'Selenium-server-standalone.jar' and 'Selenium Client & WebDriver'. Following is the link from SeleniumHQ.org website [http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/]..

1. http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/2.44/selenium-server-standalone-2.44.0.jar
2. "http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/2.44/selenium-java-2.44.0.zip"

I know first one is Formerly known as Selenium RC and second one is Selenium 2.0(Webdriver). But Is the latest version supporting all the jars in Webdriver in Selenium Server. I have only Selenium Server available, Did all the method's in Selenium Webdriver supports in Selenium Server? likewise, what are the differences between the jars in it?

could pls help

/Thanks

Answer (score 41):

I see a bit of confusion here... Regarding "***Selenium WebDriver***" & "***Selenium Server***"

***Selenium WebDriver 2.0*** - helps to write scripts for automating browsers..this package provides us with classes & methods to achieve automation. After writing scripts we can run them on LOCAL MACHINE and see automation ourselves. WebDriver projects were merged with selenium RC to overcome the drawbacks of selenium RC making it selenium WebDriver 2.0

***Selenium Server:*** Now once i have my scripts (as mentioned above),To run scripts on REMOTE MACHINES (Test Beds) and NOT ON LOCAL MACHINE we do it using ***selenium server***. So in short ***Selenium Webdriver*** works together with ***Selenium Server***..they co-exist to help and not to replace each other.

I hope this helps

Answer (score 8):

From Selenium WebDriver official Documentation:

> **WebDriver and the Selenium-Server** You may, or may not, need the
>   Selenium Server, depending on how you intend to use
>   Selenium-WebDriver. If your browser and tests will all run on the same
>   machine, and your tests only use the WebDriver API, then you do not
>   need to run the Selenium-Server; WebDriver will run the browser
>   directly.
>
> There are some reasons though to use the Selenium-Server with
>   Selenium-WebDriver.
>
> - You are using Selenium-Grid to distribute your tests over multiple  machines or virtual machines (VMs).
> - You want to connect to a remote machine that has a particular browser version that is not on your current machine.
> - You are not using the Java bindings (i.e. Python, C#, or Ruby) and would like to use HtmlUnit Driver

References:

1. http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#webdriver-and-the-selenium-server

Comment: for [JavaScript binding](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/tree/master/javascript/node/selenium-webdriver), it can run without selenium-server. The 3rd point of official selenium doc may not all collect.

Comment: "for JavaScript binding, it can run without selenium-server.". you are using "javascript bindings'. Here third point says that you can use "selenium-server" if not using client-bindings (javascript, java etc) you need at least one of them. simple thumb rule for me is that "client bindings - develop and run scripts in local machine" & "selenium-server -
 run scripts in remote machines."

Answer (score 1):

Selenium-server-standalone.jar is used for executing tests through Selenium Grid for distributing the test in multiple nodes and browsers.

Selenium Web Driver is used for executing in one machine in one browser at a time.